# Troubelshoot timeout on NFS mount

Tags: nfs, mount

On a archlinux client I'm attempting to connect to a QNAP nfs export. The export is nfsv4.
The showmount shows the correct exports:

```
[root@helene j]# showmount -e 192.168.111.1
Export list for 192.168.111.1:
/Public *
/media  192.168.111.2
```

Nmap shows

```
[root@helene j]# nmap -Pn 192.168.111.1
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-06-04 09:29 CEST
Nmap scan report for daphnis.kingma (192.168.111.1)
Host is up (0.00039s latency).
Not shown: 984 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    filtered ssh
80/tcp    filtered http
111/tcp   filtered rpcbind
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp   filtered https
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
873/tcp   filtered rsync
2049/tcp  filtered nfs
3493/tcp  filtered nut
5900/tcp  filtered vnc
8080/tcp  filtered http-proxy
8081/tcp  filtered blackice-icecap
8088/tcp  filtered radan-http
8089/tcp  filtered unknown
30000/tcp filtered ndmps
49152/tcp filtered unknown
```

Attempts to mount results in :

```
[root@helene j]# mount -t nfs 191.168.111.1:/media /srv/media
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

pings take 0.5ms.

Comment: Try with '-t nfs4'

Comment: Thanks. The timeout was caused by another problem all together. Due to a couple of failed logon attempt the QNAP put the ip of the client on the block list. But I try the nfs4 mount type